# How can i call android speech-to-text functions from java script code in the web app?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, speech-to-text

I have a simple web-app, Html page with a simple javascript script in it and an android app that has a webview in it to show the html page and i need to call the android methods from the javascript.
However it works with showToast() when i click on a button in the html

How can i call this speak() method from android in the js code??

```
public class WebAppInterface {

            public MainActivity mainActivity;

            Context mContext;

            /**
             * Instantiate the interface and set the context
             */
            WebAppInterface(Context c) {
                mContext = c;
            }

            /**
             * Show a toast from the web page
             */
            @JavascriptInterface
            public void showToast(String toast) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            /**
             * Start the speechToText from the web page
             * */

            @JavascriptInterface
            public void startSpeak(){
                mainActivity.speak();
            }



        }




        Here is the speech to text code:





          private void speak() {
                Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE, Locale.getDefault());
                intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT,"Say something");

                try{
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT);
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    Toast.makeText(this,""+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }


            }

            @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                switch (requestCode){
                    case REQUEST_CODE_SPEECH_INPUT:{
                        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && null!=data){
                            ArrayList<String> result = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
                            mTextTv.setText(result.get(0));
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Here is the html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Say hello" onClick="showAndroidToast('Hello Android!')" />
    </div>
    <hr>
    <hr>
    <div>
        <input type="button" value="Record" onClick="speak()" />
    </div>
    <div>
        <h1>Here goes the generated text:</h1>
        <p id="toText"> genText </p>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var genText = 'testing now'
        genText = Android.getTextGen();


        function speak() {
            Android.showToast("start Recording")
            Android.startSpeak();
        }


        function showAndroidToast(toast) {
            Android.showToast(toast);
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```